# I need the expression of a function which goes to infinity as x goes to 0 and has a finite integral

Tags: integration, functions, convergence-divergence, continuity

Is there a function similar to the one in the image that has a discontinuity in the origin, for which:

$$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x)=0$$

and
$$\lim_{x \to 0^{\pm}} f(x)=+\infty$$
and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \,dx=C$$ where C is a finite number?

I would need the expression of such a function.

[image]

Comment: @QC_QAOA That won't work because it doesn't have finite integral (it goes to $0$ too slowly as $x\to\infty$; but, you could certainly do something like $\begin{cases}\lvert x\rvert^{-1/2} & \lvert x\rvert\leq 1\\\lvert x\rvert^{-2} & \text{else}\end{cases}$

Comment: @NickPeterson an example with a function not defined with two conditions? Just $f(x)=something   \, \forall x$, exists?

Comment: @markvs the integral isn't convergent

Comment: @NickPeterson Yeah, I wrote the comment just answering the title but then I read the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 
          \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & x\leq 1 \\
          \frac{1}{x^2} & x\geq 1 
       \end{cases}$$

Then define

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
          0 & x=0 \\
          g(x) & x>0 \\
          g(-x) & x<0  
       \end{cases}$$

Then all your conditions are satisfied and

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=6$$

Comment: Thanks, this is ok with my conditions. Is it possible to find a function defined in only one way $\forall x$ which satisfies all the conditions?

Comment: Yes, pick $f(x) = e^{-x^2} \vert x \vert^{-1/2}$. The only reason the function is split is as $\vert x \vert^{-1/2}$ does not have enough decay at infinity for the integral to converge. The additional exponential decay fixes that and does not change the singularity at the origin.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes, thank you so much. Perfect.

Comment: @Salmone You are welcome. Maybe for a future question. Try to specify requests like this in the main text. Not all people read all the comments. It is easier to get answer tailored to your needs if it clear at first glance what exactly you are looking for :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven If I want the function to be $L^2$, which function could I pick? (all other conditions must be met) (maybe I have to ask in another question)

Comment: Just do the $\sqrt{e^{-x^2}|x|^{-1/2}}$

Comment: @QC_QAOA I was going to suggest to play with the exponent, but your answer is of course much more elegant

Comment: @QC_QAOA oh yes, you're right